# How to subclass array.array and have its derived constructor take no parameters in python?

Tags: python, constructor, new-operator

I want to encapsulate a python array to fix it's typecode and hide it from the user. I thought I could use derivation to accomplish this, but I am not able to construct my Type because it is missing a required parameter:

```
class MyBinaryBuffer(array.array):
    def __init__(self):
        array.array.__init__(self, 'B') #this is the fixed 'B' typecode parameter for 
                                  #array.array() constructor

myBuffer = MyBinaryBuffer()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: array() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

How could I implement this in a natural way?

After some research, I see that I should use the constructor instead.

**EDIT:** Sven Marnach suggested to add self which pointed me to add the missing cls parmeter in the **__*new*__** version which **works**.

```
class MyBinaryBuffer(array.array):
    def __new__(cls):
        return super(MyBinaryBuffer, cls).__new__(cls, 'B')

myBuffer = MyBinaryBuffer()
```

Comment: The code above that uses `__new__` works for me; no SyntaxError or TypeError.

Comment: @senderle: yes, with suggestions from others, I found the solution and edited my answer. the ____new____ call was missing a cls first parameter. The accepted answer also has more info on the preferred implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `__new__` method, since `__init__` gets it already constructed. But You don't use `super` there.

```
class OctetString(array):
    def __new__(cls):
        return array.__new__(cls, 'c')
```

Comment: Why not use `super` here? I've never heard that before. (Unless you're just generally against super.) In any case, I don't think that's causing the problem, because the above code using super works fine.

Comment: A couple of reasons. It's not safe and Python itself warns against it: `TypeError: object.__new__(SuperArray) is not safe, use array.array.__new__()`. Another is just performance. `super` searches the MRO (usually of an instance, which you don't have yet in `__new__`), whereas the given method is more direct. I'm not opposed to using `super` in instance constructors.

Comment: I take your point about performance. But -- sorry, this is a bit trivial -- how did you get that error message to appear? I get nothing of the like subclassing array with super. Do later versions of python start warning against it?

Comment: @senderle That may be the case. I used 2.7.1.

Comment: @Keith About use `__new__` not `__init__`. The Python documentation offers no hints about this. Did I overlook something in the docs? Where did you find information about this? If there is some definitive source, please add a link to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add own attributes use **new** and **init** :

example:

```
class Point(array.array):
    '''
    an array.array with 3 coordinates [x,y,z]
    '''

    def __new__(cls, clist, parent=None, index=-1):
        while len(clist)<3: clist.append(0.0)
        return super(Point, cls).__new__(cls,'f', clist[0:3])


    def __init__(self, cList=[], parent=None, index=-1):
        self._parent = parent  # private
        self.index   = index   # public

    @property
    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

p = Point([1,2], parent='anyObject', index=5)
print(p, p.parent, p.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method tested in both python2.x and python3.x:

```
from array import array


class MyBinaryBuffer(array):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyBinaryBuffer, cls).__new__(cls, 'B', *args, **kwargs)


b1 = MyBinaryBuffer([1, 2, 3])
b2 = MyBinaryBuffer()
print(b1, b2)
```

or if you want to avoid using `super`:

```
class MyBinaryBuffer(array):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return array.__new__(cls, 'B', *args, **kwargs)
```

In this particular case, you'll be able to fully emulate the `array.array` behaviour, other existing answers won't guarantee that.